# Import collection .json in mongodb

Tags: json, windows, mongodb, collections, console

I would like to know where is the error when trying to import a .json collection in mongodb
This is what im putting on console
`mongoimport.exe --db aloha --collection restaurants C:\Users\Xult\Downloads\restaurants.json --jsonArray`

and this is what i get

```
error validating settings: only one positional argument is allowed
```

Comment: Do you need --file before specifying the path/file?

Comment: If i put it like that  `mongoimport.exe --db aloha --collection restaurants --file C:\Users\Xult\Downloads\restaurants.json --jsonArray` i just get `error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)`

Comment: The help text for mongoimport shows the flag for selecting the database as `-d, --db=<database-name>                        database to use` try using the equal sign instead of space for both `--db` and `--collection`

Comment: I just tried and I still have the same error

Comment: The filename must be the last parameter in the call.  You include another parameter after the filename `--jsonArray`.  Move this before the file name...